# Get the URLs - HTTP Connection

Tags: java, servlets, httpconnection

I know that there are a lot of questions regarding this subject, but I still don't get it. 
I want to get the current URL from my browser in my program. What do I need to succeed? 
The connection has to be made with HTTP Connection? A proxy server would help me more? because i have to filter those URLs. Help me please, I am so confused.

Comment: The `HttpServletRequest` has all the info that you want (well, technically it does not know the URL in the browser, only *the URL that has been requested*)

Answer (score 0):

```
request.getRequestURL();
```

will get you the URL from HttpServletRequest. More documentation can be found in https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html